# Disabling NDEF Push for an Android Activity on SGS3

Tags: android

I'm trying to prevent certain activities from firing up the default "*touch to beam*" behaviour.

According to the [javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessageCallback%28android.nfc.NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...%29), using:

`nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(null, this);`

OR

`nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);`

should completely disable NDEF push for the specified activity(s) and additionally:

> This also disables any default NDEF message the Android OS would have otherwise sent on your behalf for those activity(s).

This works **perfectly** on my Nexus 7 (running 4.2.1) but **fails** to behave as intended on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (running 4.0.4) - I still get prompted to "*touch to beam*".

I've also tried adding the following to my manifest, with no luck:

`<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.disable_beam_default" android:value="true" />`

Just wondering if there's anything obvious that I've missed / am doing wrong, or if anyone else has encountered something similar?

Comment: Ok, updated my SGS3 to 4.1.1 and the problem isn't present any more. I guess this means that it's either an issue with 4.0.4, a deliberate no-op in 4.0.4, or an issue with the SGS3 4.0.4 image? Is there a nice way to find out?